# How to minify/uglify webworker bundles built with Angular in production

Tags: angular, minify, web-worker

I need to use web-workers for heavy computation and Angular provides a convenient way to generate a web-worker in an application with the CLI command `ng generate web-worker app`.

The issue is, when built in production using `ng build --prod`, the generated web-worker bundle doesn't appear to be well optimized. I still can find whole variable, class or method names in the file, and some parts of the code is easy to read on the bundle, which struggles me.

Is there a way to better minify that code?

Regards,

EDIT:
To give an example, here is the content of app.worker.ts:

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
class MyClassName{
  myMethodName(){}
}
const myVariableName = new MyClassName()
postMessage(myVariableName.myMethodName());
```

And this can be found inside the worker.js file generated with `ng build --prod`

```
const myVariableName=new class{myMethodName(){}};postMessage(myVariableName.myMethodName())}});
```

the code is optimized but is still easy to read.

EDIT 2: typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it seems like it's intended that webworker files, like service-worker files, are unminified.

Minification can be made manually as [explained here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11538#issuecomment-557773917)

Answer (score 3):

edit your `angular.json` and set `optimization:true`

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#build-configs

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's actually already set to true.